# Rotating cube as child of another gameObject results in it skewing in 2 of 3 axes

Tags: unity, rotation

I have added a cube and changed its scale and position but not its rotation.
I added a second cube as a child of that first cuboid.  I was hoping to rotate it but instead it just skews the second cuboid.
The skew only happens in 2 out of 3 of the axes.
Additionally the skew does not happen if the child cuboid is not a child of the first cuboid.

Screen shots attached below.  Skew happening in one of the two axes:

[image: Skew]

Rotation correctly occurring in third axis:

[image: Rotation]

How do I rotate it in all axes?
Also as Skew seems useful.  How do you control skewing it in all axes?

Comment: can you share your code that we see what you care really doing. i cant open your images

Comment: This is due to a non-uniform scale on your parent object - [see this post for more information](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/163770/39518).

Comment: @virtouso there was no code.  I was only using the GUI editor.